# Select dependent on reactjs with react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, material-ui, react-select

I'm developing an App in ReactJS, and I have a page where I want to show two select, one dependent on the other.

I'm using `react-select` and `@material-ui`.

In `dates`:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "202001"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "202002"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "202003"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "202004"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "202005"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "202006"
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "202007"
  }
]
```

I have a list of dates that are available to select.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
...

const App = () => {

    ...

    const DateA = dates.map((item) => ({
        value: item.id,
        label: item.name,
    }));

    const DateB = dates.map((item) => ({
        value: item.id,
        label: item.name,
    }));

    const [dateA, setDateA] = React.useState(null);
    const [dateB, setDateB] = React.useState(null);

    function handleChangeDateA(value) {
        setDateA(value);
    }

    function handleChangeDateB(value) {
        setDateB(value);
    }

    return (
            <div className="App">
                <div className="col-3">
                    <Select
                        classes={classes}
                        styles={selectStyles}
                        inputId="DateA"
                        TextFieldProps={{
                            label: "DateA",
                            InputLabelProps: {
                            htmlFor: "DateA",
                            shrink: true,
                            },
                            placeholder: "DateA...",
                        }}
                        options={DateA}
                        components={components}
                        value={dateA}
                        onChange={handleChangeDateA}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="col-3">
                    <Select
                        classes={classes}
                        styles={selectStyles}
                        inputId="DateB"
                        TextFieldProps={{
                            label: "DateB",
                            InputLabelProps: {
                                htmlFor: "DateB",
                                shrink: true,
                            },
                            placeholder: "DateB...",
                        }}
                        options={DateB}
                        components={components}
                        value={dateB}
                        onChange={handleChangeDateB}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

The idea is that the `DateB` select take dates greater than the ones selected in the `DateA` select.

How can I do this, suggestions?

Comment: you can set the value of DateB conditionally after the DateA selected

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How can i do what you suggest?

Comment: You can use useEffect for listening changes in DateA and then you will check the value of DateA and condtionally set the value in DateB,which is greater than value of DateA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (condition) {
         setDateB(value)
    }
          
   }, [DateA])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Yes, something like this could be implemented. What condition do I establish?